# django.contrib.auth.urls is no longer working after creating a Custom User model

Tags: python, django

I created a Custom user model from AbstractUserModel. I'm using django.contrib.auth.urls for simple login and logout functionalities including password_reset and When i'm still using the default user model of django, but its no longer working on my Custom user model. Is there a way to make this work for custom user model.

(1146, "Table 'db.auth_user' doesn't exist") this is the error message i'm getting every time i login a sample account to my application. Thanks

Comment: How did you construct a custom user model? Did you set the user model in the settings?

Comment: Yes. " AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.User' " I add this line to my settings.py

Answer (score 0):

I think if you created your own user profile then you should create your forms and views
for this

P.S: This is how i understood all the things about
[AbstracUser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HshbjK1vDtY&t=1509s)